# Bypass the check if the Username is unchanged in the form

Tags: php, mysql

**FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>

</head>
<body>


<form id='updateholder' action='updateacc.php' method='post'>
            <fieldset >
                <legend>Update Account</legend>

Username:
                <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value = "<?php echo $row['user_Username']?>"/>
Current Password:
                <input type='text' name='curpassword' id='curpassword' value = "" maxlength="50" />
New Password:
                <input type='text' name='confirm' id='newpassword'   value = "" maxlength="50" />
Confirm New Password:
                <input type='text' name='confirm' id='confirmpassword'   value = "" maxlength="50" />
Middle Name:
                <input type='text' name='middlename' id='middlename' value = "<?php echo $row['user_Mname']?>"/>
Last Name:
                <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' value = "<?php echo $row['user_Lname']?>"/>

                <input type='Submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

<a href = "logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update.php**

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include('dbconn.php'); 

    $user_ID = $_SESSION['user_ID'] ;


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_ID = '$user_ID'"; 

      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                $username    = $_POST["username"];
                $curpassword = $_POST["curpassword"];
                $middlename  = $_POST["middlename"];
                $lastname    = $_POST["lastname"];

                $username   = trim(mysqli_escape_string($con, $username));
                $curpassword   = trim(mysqli_escape_string($con, $curpassword));
                $middlename = trim(mysqli_escape_string($con, $middlename));
                $lastname   = trim(mysqli_escape_string($con, $lastname));

                $sql2= "SELECT user_Username FROM tbl_user WHERE user_Username='$username'";
                $sql3= "SELECT user_Password FROM tbl_user WHERE user_ID='$accholder_ID'";
                $result2  = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
                $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
                $row2    = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $row3    = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            echo "Sorry...This Username already exist..";
        }  else {
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "Update tbl_user SET user_Mname = "$middlename", user_Lname = "$lastname", user_Username = "$username", user_Password = "$curpassword"");

            if ($query) {
                echo "Account Updated";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I have a Code here that shows the data of the tbl_user in html form

but when it checks if the username existed 
it will always `echo "Sorry...This Username already exist.."`
Since it will also include his own existing username in the check if it is submitted

Is there a way to bypass the check if the Username is unchanged

Comment: Instead of posting everything in the question, please create a kind of test case that creates the problem that you are facing. It would help you to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bypass check for unchanged username just add one check like:

**Example**:

```
if(trim($_POST["username"]) == $row['user_Username']){
   //return unchanged username stuff
}
else{
   // your stuff for changed username
}
```

If form value and database values are same it means `username` is unchanged else changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check directly by

```
if($_POST["username"] == $row['user_Username'])
{
   echo "User Name Matched";
}
else
{
  echo "Unique User Name";
}
```